# np.multiply or pd.mul but what multiplying array to use depends on conditions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two DataFrames `df1` and `df2` and two arrays `mul1` and `mul2`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [100, 200], 'B': [50, 150], 'C': [40, 120]})
#      A    B    C
# 0  100   50   40
# 1  200  150  120
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [5, 1], 'B': [3, 25], 'C': [10, 11]})
#    A   B   C
# 0  5   3  10
# 1  1  25  11

mul1 = np.array([.1, .2, .3])
mul2 = np.array([1.1, 1.2, 1.3])
```

I would like to use something like `pd.mul` or `np.multiply` to multiply `df1` by elements in either `mul1` or `mul2` depending on their corresponding values in `df2`.

For column A, `df1` needs to be multiplied by the `mul1[0]` if `df2['A'] > 3`, otherwise it needs to be multiplied by `mul2[0]`.

For columns B and C, the corresponding criteria is `df2['B'] > 12` and `df2['C'] > 15`.

So the correct output is:

```
    A    B   C
0   10   60  52
1  220   30  156
```

Does anyone have a good way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using np.where, we can specify a condition in the 1st parameter, and the operations we want in the 2nd and 3rd parameters:

```
df1['A'] = np.where(df2['A'] > 3, df1['A'] * mul1[0], df1['A'] * mul2[0])
df1['B'] = np.where(df2['B'] > 12, df1['B'] * mul1[1], df1['B'] * mul2[1])
df1['C'] = np.where(df2['C'] > 15, df1['C'] * mul1[2], df1['C'] * mul2[2])
```

Comment: This is almost what I am looking for. The additional complication I am having is that in my actual code, mul1 and mul2 are dataframes with column headers [A,B,C] and I am trying to locate the right values using the loc function (example: mul1['values'].loc[mul1['headings'] == 'A']). When I do this the output array is NaNs everywhere except the diagonals. Any advice?

Comment: I have figured it out.  Adding .values[0] to the end solved the problem.